# How to remove quotes in sybase ASE

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I have a string:

> "16680,16678,16677,16676,16675,16672"

Which I got from the Stored procedure passed parameter while calling it. I want to insert these records in where in like

> Where in (16680,16678,16677,16676,16675,16672).

How can I make this in Sybase ASE stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str_replace()` function to replace the double quotes with NULL, eg:

```
declare @strings varchar(15)

select  @strings = '"1,2,3,4,5"'

select  @strings, str_replace(@strings,'"',NULL)
go

 --------------- ---------------
 "1,2,3,4,5"     1,2,3,4,5
```

Feeding the new string into a query requires a bit more work though.

Trying to feed directly into a query generates an error, eg:

```
declare @strings varchar(15)

select  @strings = '"1,2,3,4,5"'

select id from sysobjects where id in ( str_replace(@strings,'"',NULL) )
go

Msg 257, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ASE400', Line 7:
Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

To get around this issue we can dynamically build the query and then run it via an `execute()` call, eg:

```
declare @strings varchar(15),
        @query   varchar(100)

select  @strings = '"1,2,3,4,5"'

select  @query = 'select id from sysobjects where id in (' || str_replace(@strings,'"',NULL) || ')'

print   @query

execute (@query)
go

select id from sysobjects where id in (1,2,3,4,5)

 id
 -----------
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
```

Another solution that does away with the `@query` variable:

```
declare @strings varchar(15)

select  @strings = '"1,2,3,4,5"'
select  @strings = str_replace(@strings,'"',NULL)

execute( 'select id from sysobjects where id in (' || @strings || ')' )
go

 id
 -----------
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
```

**NOTE:** all code was run in an `ASE 16.0 SP04 GA` instance.